# Spring Cloud Zookeeper and Feign deployed on AWS ECS with Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-ecs, spring-cloud-zookeeper

I have two Spring Boot applications, both using Spring Cloud Zookeeper for service discovery, and  one of them uses Feign to talk to the other, as described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-zookeeper)

It all works fine when deployed on localhost and as docker images via `docker-compose` but when deploying as separate Tasks/Services to AWS ECS (using the default networking mode of `awsvpc`), the communication between the two no longer works and the Feign client errors out with:

```
feign.FeignException$NotFound: [404 ] during [GET] to [http://my-api/api/workspace-context] [APIKeyService#getContextFromAPIKey(String)]: [<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} ... (431 bytes)]
```

Note that the response here kind of looks like the standard Tomcat 404 response.

I have seen the values stored in Zookeeper for this AWS deployment, and it seems it puts an IP address as the value for `address`, which I am not sure is correct.

```json
{
    "name": "my-api",
    "id": "323be0b7-8ad8-4061-846e-abcdac2bbbca",
    "address": "169.254.xxx.xxx",
    "port": 8080,
    "sslPort": null,
    ...
```

This IP address matches neither the public nor the private IP of the ENI associated with the ECS task.

If I manually replace the `address` value of that Zookeeper entry with the ENI's public IP, it starts working corectly again (but not with the private IP). But obviously, it would be broken again after a new deployment.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Cloud makes a guess as to what host or IP address to use. If there's an env var set on the host that contains the public IP you can use that to set the `address`.

```
spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.instanceIpAddress=${MY_IP_ENV_VAR}
```

Otherwise, according to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#ignore-network-interfaces), you can configure network interfaces to ignore:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      ignoredInterfaces:
        - docker0
        - ecs-eth0 #ecs private network
        - veth.*
```

or what IP address ranges to prefer:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      preferredNetworks:
        - 192.168
        - 10.0
```

Comment: Thanks - I did have a look at those, but I am not sure how AWS sets the IP address (and it changes when you re-deploy it). I guess I will have to dig deeped into AWS ECS

Comment: OK, so after (temporarily) enabling SSH on my container and inspecting the available network interfaces inside it using `ifconfig -a`, I found out that the `169.254.xxx.xxx` IP addres comes from an interface called `ecs-eth0`. Adding that to the `ignoredInterfaces` property made it work correctly.

Comment: UPDATE: AWS Fargate seem to have changed the network name they use in platform version 1.4.0 - the one that was called `ecs-eth0` before is now called `eth0`, so had to add that to `ignoredInterfaces` instead.